RDLC para VS - Como puedo hacer que una tabla de RDCL ocupe toda la pagina sin importar la cantidad de lineas que tenga?
Estoy haciendo un reporte en RDLC For VS en donde tengo la siguiente tabla:

Pero cuando creo una factura este se muestra asi, ocupando solo lo necesario:

Me estan pidiendo que si hay alguna forma de que la tabla se muestre asi, que se rellene con lineas "vacias" para que ocupe el tamaño de la pagina.

